Mailkit: How to connect to Office365 Business Account to read emails
I am new using Mailkit in c# and having trouble with connecting with IMAP to an office365 business account. I receive an error message that the authentication failed. I like to create an application to read the emails. With a usual office365 account it worked fine. There is no two factor authentication in place where I should use an app password. And I don't use Azure.
using MailKit.Net.Imap;


    private void Connect(string host, int port, string email, string password)
    {
        ImapClient _client = new ImapClient();

        _client.Connect(host, port, true);

        _client.Authenticate(email, password);

        _client.Disconnect(true);
    }


"App-specific passwords" aren't related to 2FA, they are just an alternative way of giving access to a specific application (by giving each app a different password). This is started to become a requirement for various large email services because they are increasingly not accepting your real password for anything but the web-based UI.

If using an app-specific password is not an option for you, then you will likely need to follow the instructions for setting up an OAuth2.0 authentication workflow: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md

"App-specific passwords" aren't related to 2FA, they are just an alternative way of giving access to a specific application (by giving each app a different password). This is started to become a requirement for various large email services because they are increasingly not accepting your real password for anything but the web-based UI.
If using an app-specific password is not an option for you, then you will likely need to follow the instructions for setting up an OAuth2.0 authentication workflow: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md

Thank you very much, I try to check that out but I cannot understand how to register the application in Azure? Because I like to read emails from different third parties

You've got to read the Microsoft Azure documentation.
